# NgbDropdown in Navbar w/ routerLink does not redirect

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I've been trying to create a navbar in which the main link (the dropdown header) takes me to a page, and then using a dropdown-split with a list of anchors that can redirect to other business-related links. The problem is that the dropdown children are not redirecting anywhere. If I put the link on another item from the navbar, it works fine.

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/s2yGUvWhY0pU3j4qh0lt

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="link1">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="nav-link">Link 1</button>
    <div ngbDropdown placement="bottom-left" class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle-split nav-link" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" routerLink="link2">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Angular: 5.2.5

ng-bootstrap: 1.0.0

Bootstrap: 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the link 1 router link inside the button. It was overriding everything at the li level.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" >
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" routerLink="/link1">Link 1</a></button>
        <div ngbDropdown placement="bottom-left" class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle-split nav-link" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" routerLink="/link2">Link 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: `<a class="nav-link dropdown-item" routerLink="/link1">Link 1</a>` kinda messed up the look of the navbar. It works just fine with `<button class="nav-link" routerLink="link1" routerLinkActive="active">
                Link 1
              </button>`